# How to compile and integrate ffmpeg with openssl support?

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg, openssl, cross-compilation

How can I cross-compile FFMPEG for ARM with openssl support?

I have tried normal compilation of FFMPEG, but I need openssl support also.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the procedure you used/instructions you have followed

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to get the ffmpeg cross compiled with openssl support,
The below git link is what i used.
The instructions are given in the readme file .
https://github.com/Khang-NT/ffmpeg-binary-android

Comment: Can you please add the steps here? A link is not considered an answer on Stack Exchange sites

Comment: ok sure,here is what have to be done.Downlaod the repo from the above link,export the path for the android NDK and specify the arch as arm.FLAVOR=full       # or "lite"
TARGET=armv7-a    # Support targets: "arm", "armv7-a", "arm-v7n", "arm64-v8a", "i686", "x86_64"
BUILD_DIR=$(pwd)/build_dir
FINAL_DIR=$(pwd)/final/$TARGET


./build_ffmpeg.sh $TARGET $FLAVOR $BUILD_DIR $FINAL_DIR.....................please look at the above link for more details,its self explanatory

Comment: could you please [edit] the info into your post? It's not readable in comments. It might seem like I'm being a pedant, but this site is for sharing knowledge to help future visitors. It should be more helpful than just a link. I would edit your answer myself but I don't understand exactly what you did and I'm working hard right now and don't have time. So, it would be so nice if you could fix it, then I could upvote your answer and that would mark the question as answered

Comment: @Zanna first i have downloaded the content from https://github.com/Khang-NT/ffmpeg-binary-android.git                                                                         Then browse to the above downloaded directory and then type the following

Comment: FLAVOR=full                                                                                                                        TARGET=armv7-a         //for us it was for arm 7 device.                                       BUILD_DIR=$(pwd)/build_dir                                                                                      FINAL_DIR=$(pwd)/final/$TARGET                                                                           After typing the above 4 lines..export the path of your NDK by,

Comment: Instead of trying to cram the instructions into unreadable comments, you should just [edit] your answer to add this info.